# Creating UDK projects in external folders

Tags: svn, unrealscript

I am using a school computer and asked the administrators to install UDK on it. While reading the documentation, I came across the [folder structures](http://udn.epicgames.com/Three/DevelopmentKitFirstScriptProject.html#Project%20setup). It tells me that I need to put my source inside the UDK installation folder. Is there a possibility not to do so? I cannot reach this folder, since it is public for all other users.

I would like to use SVN with it as well. If not, then UDK is probably not the best option for me to use for this school project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, even if you were able to keep your source code in an outside folder, you still need to be able to access the `UDKGame` game folder in order to save compiled scripts, generate and edit config files, and store game assets.

I can't say for sure, but since the UDK has been installed on the computer -- and thus all the UDK prerequisites have been installed -- if you put a duplicate copy of the UDK folder somewhere where you had write access, there's a chance you might be able to develop with it that way.

Comment: Thank you. Too bad it doesn't work this way. I found the same problem with cryEngine. Both engines seem to be built to simply have one game in development. It is not a good engine too create simple set ups en spike solutions probably then...